# UIViewController with UITextField: dismiss view controller AFTER dismiss keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a view controller that has a text field, the view controller is presented modally with a Cancel button in navigation bar. When user taps the Cancel button while editing the text field, I want to first dismiss the keyboard, then dismiss the view controller, otherwise the view controller dismisses and the keyboard remains on the presenting view controller of a bit less than 1 second before dismissing.

The way I dismiss the keyboard is to use

```
[textField resignFirstResponder]
```

However it doesn't have a completion block for the animation, and I don't want to use magic number to delay the dismiss of view controller after certain time interval.

Is there a way to work this out?

Thanks!

Comment: you can try this -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: where did you put dismiss keyboard code ??